# change css on scroll, depending on screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

So I'm using this JQuery to change elements in my header on scroll. Is it possible to only have these changes happen depending on screensize?

Code:

```
     $(window).scroll(function() {

    //After scrolling 100px from the top...
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= 10 ) {
        $('#scrollthing').css('display', 'none');
        $('#ticket-amount').css('margin-bottom', '15px');

    //Otherwise remove inline styles and thereby revert to original stying
    } else {
        $('#scrollthing').attr('style', '');

    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can make any jquery condition by view port size. But what is your problem here?

Comment: I made my website responsive with bootstrap. I use this code to make my 'fixed' header smaller on screens below 400px. But with this code, it also affects other screensizes. I don't know a lot about Jquery, how would I add such a condition? 

thank you for the reply

Comment: I cannot answer my own question for some reason.. Anyway, I found the condition you're talking about:     if ( $(window).width() < 405 ) {

Comment: yes you can use `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` to get view port height width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the width and height of the **viewport**:

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
```

resize event of the page:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
      //do your check here on resize
      if($(window).width() < 405 )
         //do here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Here you go.




$(window).scroll(function() {
// checking the  condition
if ($(window).width() < 400 && $(window).scrollTop() >= 10) {
// set your changes here
}
else { 
// else condition for when the if condition does not apply
}
});
```

This is not very optimal for performance, but should do the job. You could wrap it in a document ready function if you want.